# Question about Null vs zero

Tags: c++, string, case

I have this function:

```
void ToUpper(char * S)
{
    while (*S!=0)
    {
       *S=(*S >= 'a' && *S <= 'z')?(*S-'a'+'A'):*S;
       S++;
    }
}
```

What does it mean for *S != 0, should it be null instead?

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you don’t indent any of your codes properly? Properly indented code is *vastly* better to read.

Comment: My editor messed up the indent during cut and paste. i've fixed it now. thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That is checking for the end of the string which is a character which has the value of zero. It is not connected to NULL pointers in any way.

Comment: That's the correct answer, but as it happens 0 is the same as a NULL.

Comment: Also, I think it's clearer to use `'\0'` when you mean an end-of-string marker and `NULL` when you mean a non-pointing pointer. Yes, they're all zero in a sense but it is better to keep the *concepts* separate.

Comment: NULL is implementation specific I don't think the specification mandates NULL to equal 0

Comment: @John: The C++ standard requires NULL to be #defined as 0.  However, the actual bits stored in a null pointer don't have to be zero.

Comment: @John: I'm quite sure the literal 0 in the code, when used with pointers, has to signify a NULL pointer (if the actual address is any different from 0, this has to be completely transparent to the user).

Comment: @dan04 The standard requires that `NULL`, as defined in <cstddef> be an implementation defined null-pointer constant.  Probably 0, but it could also be 0L or some other value.  More to the point, it does *not* require that `NULL` not be defined in other headers to be whatever you want.  While comparing to `NULL` is more expressive, it is also more error prone.

Comment: @Dennis: While `NULL` could be something else, I really can't see any sane compiler writer wanting to go that way given that interconversion with 0 *is* mandated. (Some big-iron compilers are clearly not written by sane folks. They also break the assumption that a `void*` and a `char*` are the same size. It's easiest to just pretend that such horrors don't exist, to be honest.)

Comment: Confusingly, ASCII character 0 *is* named `NUL`.

Comment: Wouldn't you just write "while (*s)" ?

Comment: @Donal: It doesn't have to be compiler writers.  `NULL` is not a reserved word; anybody can `#define NULL (void*)0` if they feel so inclined.  I've worked with libraries that did just that, and its annoying.

Comment: @Martin: You can do that. I prefer to use `'\0'` for clarity. (Naturally it makes no difference to the generated code.)

Answer (score 4):

I would write it `*S != '\0'` as I feel that is more idiomatic, but that is really just personal style preference. You are checking for the null character (ASCII NUL).

You might also consider checking `S != 0` before any of that code as the pointer itself may be null, and you don't want to dereference a null pointer.

Answer (score 0):

`NULL` is defined differently in `C` and `C++`

in `C`

```
#define NULL 0
```

in `C++`

```
#define NULL (void*) 0
```

Answer (score -1):

I like algorithms better than loops:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstring>
#include <cctype>

void ToUpper(char* p)
{
    std::transform(p, p + strlen(p), p, toupper);
}
```

This solution also works for character encodings where a to z aren't sequential.

Just for fun, here is an experiment that only does one iteration with algorithms:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>
#include <cstring>
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

struct cstring_iterator : std::iterator<std::random_access_iterator_tag, char>
{
    char* p;

    cstring_iterator(char* p = 0) : p(p) {}

    char& operator*()
    {
        return *p;
    }

    cstring_iterator& operator++()
    {
        ++p;
        return *this;
    }

    bool operator!=(cstring_iterator that) const
    {
        assert(p);
        assert(!that.p);
        return *p != '\0';
    }
};

void ToUpper(char* p)
{
    std::transform(cstring_iterator(p), cstring_iterator(),
                   cstring_iterator(p), toupper);
}

int main()
{
    char test[] = "aloha";
    ToUpper(test);
    std::cout << test << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I like algorithms better too, in general. But here you are actually looping over the length of the string twice.

Comment: This question is marked C++, so why is Mike using `char*` in the first place? `std::string` to the rescue! Anyway, looping over an array twice is still linear complexity ;)

Comment: Sorry, but your iterator implementation is wrong; it misses many random_iterator operations, and the inequality operator is really brain-damaged.

Comment: @jpalecek That's why I preceded the code by *Just for fun, here is an experiment*

Answer (score -1):

NULL is a pointer while *S is the value stored at the pointer. Thankes to Dennis Ritchie, the digit 0 is acceotable as both.